# Looking for other ways to say "run out of quickly"

Tags: word-request

I was talking to one of my friends on the phone today when he mentioned to me that he had got a phone plan that only got him 3GB of data which is really not that much nowadays if you wanna browse through FaceBook watch vids on YouTube and etc...

After he finished saying that I said "You know... 3GBs is really...." and then I paused and in my head, I was like, what should I tell him? 3GBs is really easy to run out of?

Then I ended up saying what I thought "3GBs is really easy to run out of", after saying that and gotten off the phone I started thinking... What other idioms could I have used to say that he would use up all his data very quickly with that amount?

So that is my question what other idioms exist out there that could replace "to run out of quickly"?

Comment: "3GBs won't last long!"

Comment: You'll soon use up 3GBs of data.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options.

> 3GB will (or can) fill up quickly
>   3GB won't last long (or "won't last as long as you think")
>   3GB is less than you think

I could come up with a lot more than that with some time.

Comment: I guess you **ran out** of obvious synonyms   :)

Comment: :p Mostly I ran out of energy ;)